# How to make HTML href function to redirect the user to a world wide web page instead of a folder inside the user's computer?

Tags: html, href

I am learning HTML, and whenever I execute the href function in HTML and click the blue text, the browser tries to redirect me to a folder inside my computer, when in reality I want to enter a website. For example, if I try to execute the following code, instead of the browser redirecting me to duckduckgo.com, it tries to redirect me to a folder inside my computer:

```
<a href="duckduckgo.com">Browse anonymously and without being traced</a>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `href="duckduckgo.com"` is using a relative URL, so the browser is looking for `duckduckgo.com` relative to the current URL that is displaying the page.  To the browser it's no different than if you used `href="index.html"`, both are structurally identical.

Instead, use a fully-qualified URL:

```
<a href="http://duckduckgo.com">Browse anonymously and without being traced</a>
```

---

You can also default to the current protocol with this:

```
<a href="//duckduckgo.com">Browse anonymously and without being traced</a>
```

So if the current page is open via `http://` or `https://` then the link would use the same in the resulting request.  Note however that your description of *"a folder inside my computer"* may somewhat imply that your current protocol could be `file://`, in which case an inferred protocol clearly wouldn't work.  The point is, the structure of a complete URL is pretty versatile so you have options.